# How are weak measurements taken into account in collapse models?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

Collapse models have been introduced to solve the measurement problem in quantum mechanics. In collapse models the localization of wavefunction is not considered to be due to any kind of measurement but, rather as a intrinsic property of all physical systems. The collapse strength as well as time varies with mass and hence explaining the absence of position superpositions in the macroscopic world.

But, I have been looking into weak measurements lately and was thinking about how weak measurements and its results are taken into account in collapse models.

If collapse models are right(which we are not sure of) then, the collapse though it depends on the mass of the system will nevertheless happen. How can we define weak measurements in this scenario? How can we talk about something like "doing a measurement that wont disturb the wavefunction of the system a lot but enough to get some partial information"?

Comment: Here's someone who seems to be trying http://www.johnboccio.com/research/quantum/notes/150908253.pdf